# Google Maps API v3 I want to download marker data (lat lng) and save it to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, maps

I have a map code like this:

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.215594, 21.014130),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.215594, 21.014130),
    draggable: true
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' +
      evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(6) + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(6) + '</p>';
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragstart', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Moving marker...</p>';
  });

  map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
  myMarker.setMap(map);
}
```

I want to save the lat and lng values to the database but I don't know how to get them, I just know how to display lat and lng in js. The marker has draggable option. I can drag it to the desired location on the map and then show the dragged data of this marker (lat and lng) will be displayed by `innerHTML`.

But how now to get these values (lat and lng) after dragging them to desired position and save them to the database? My site is written in Smarty. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to add your own ajax function within the `dragend` callback to fire-off a HTTPRequest that can be used to save the lat/lng of the current marker position.

The following uses `fetch` in conjunction with `FormData` to create and send the request. In this example the request is processed by the same page but you can simply change the javascript `endpoint` variable to point to a separate PHP script to save the lat/lng.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['lat'],
        $_POST['lng']
    )){
        
        /* save to db */
        $sql='insert into `markers` (`lat`,`lng`) values (?,?)';
        # $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
        # $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_POST['lat'],$_POST['lng']);
        # $stmt->execute();
        #etc
        
        
        #prepare data to send back if appropriate
        $data=array(
            'status'=>  'success',
            'lat'   =>  $_POST['lat'],
            'lng'   =>  $_POST['lng'],
            'sql'   =>  $sql,
            'date'  =>  date( DATE_ATOM ),
            'ip'    =>  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        );
        
        # send data and exit
        exit( json_encode( $data ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        
        <style>
            body, body *{
                box-sizing:border-box;
            }
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
            #current{
                width:800px;
                float:none;
                margin:1rem auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function initMap() {

                let lat=52.215594;
                let lng=21.014130;
                
                const current=document.getElementById('current');
                const savelatlng=(e)=>{
                    let fd=new FormData();
                        fd.set('lat',e.latLng.lat());
                        fd.set('lng',e.latLng.lng());
                        
                    let endpoint=location.href; // the php script that will save the latlng
                    
                    fetch( endpoint, { method:'post', body:fd })
                        .then(r=>r.json())
                        .then(json=>{
                            console.log( 'Position saved: %o', json )
                        });
                };
                
                var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom:7,
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ),
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });

                var myMarker=new google.maps.Marker({
                    draggable:true,
                    map:map
                });
                myMarker.setPosition( map.getCenter() );


                google.maps.event.addListener( myMarker, 'dragend', function( evt ) {
                    current.innerHTML = `<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: ${evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)} Current Lng: ${evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(6)}</p>`;
                    map.setCenter( evt.latLng );
                    savelatlng( evt );
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener( myMarker, 'dragstart', function( evt ) {
                    current.innerHTML = '<p>Moving marker...</p>';
                });
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <div id='current'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```